# How to import a data from an excel column to a data grid view column winform

Tags: winforms, datagridview, import, excel-2010

I am trying to import data from an excel file to a data grid view.
My goal is to get all the records from Column 'A' in the excel file , 
to the desired column in my grid view.
I have tried to find a sample code or anything to help me acomplish my task,
but all I found was the other way around. ( datagridview ==> Excel ).

Need your help to get this done .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be done directly but you could try to import your Excel into database table(MSSQL) and then retrieve data to your Grid View.